# Seleneum Xpath click: am I doing it correctly?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click

I am trying `element.click()` however I am not sure what is the correct syntax here.

[image: Inspect Element]

My code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="col-content"]/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]")
element.click()
```

xpath: `//*[@id="col-content"]/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]`

I am getting an invalid syntax error here

error:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="col-content"]/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]")
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I insert xpath for the `click()` to execute?

Comment: You have double quotes in the middle of your string. Easiest would be to use single quotes outside, e.g., `'whatever "123" something'`.

Comment: Yes, I tried and I am getting this error when I replaced double quotes with singel quotes both ways `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='col-content']/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]"}
` and  `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='col-content']/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the full xpath in your case it will be: "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/span/a[3]"

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="col-content"]/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]')
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 
`raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="col-content"]/div[3]/div/div/span/a[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)`

Comment: try giving the full xpath in your case it will be: "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/span/a[3]"